# .soファイル生成時に他の.soファイルをリンクする方法

Tags: c++, linux

/usr/lib 等にlibhage.soがあるとして

```
g++ libhoeg.cc -lhage -fPIC -shared -o libhoge.so
```

として、とりあえずlibhoge.soは生成されます。

しかしlddでみるかぎりlibhoge.soはlibhage.soをリンクしていませんでした。

どのようにしてリンクすればよろしいでしょうか

Comment: libhoge.ccはlibhage内の関数を参照していますか?

Comment: 参照しています。hoge,hageなどとではなく、実際は、libapt-pkgの_configと_systemを参照しています。

Comment: `g++ libhoeg.cc -Wl,--no-as-needed -fPIC -shared -o libhoge.so -lhage` とするとどうなりますか？(`-lhage` は必ず最後に指定して下さい）

Comment: 最後に指定したところうまく行きました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラスを宣言・定義するだけで使用していないからでしょう。

```
#include <apt-pkg/init.h>
#include <apt-pkg/cachefile.h>
#include <apt-pkg/pkgcache.h>
#include <apt-pkg/cacheiterators.h>
class Init {
public:
        static Configuration* getConfigration() { return _config; }
        static pkgSystem* getSysstem() { return _system; }
};

Configuration *func() { return Init::getConfigration(); }
```

こういうソースならリンクされます。

```
$ g++ -o libhoge.so -fPIC -shared libhoge.cc -lapt-pkg
$ ldd libhoge.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9f7a3000)
    libapt-pkg.so.4.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12 (0x00007f393e4cf000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f393e1c0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f393ddf6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f393dbf2000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f393d9d7000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f393d7c7000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f393d5a5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f393d38f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f393d087000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f393ea37000)
```

Comment: ソースは指摘の通りです。ではこれで、libhoge.soのInit::getConfigration()を使えるようにするためにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 上のコメントは無視してください。
ソースは指摘の通りです。問題は -lapt-pkgを最後に置いていなかったためでした

Comment: 参照され得るすべての定義が、インライン関数などでヘッダファイル内で完結しているのであれば、ライブラリとしてはそのヘッダファイルを作るだけでよく、 `libhoge.so` を作る必要はそもそもないでしょう。そのようなスタイルの C++ ライブラリは STL をはじめとしてたくさんあります。